# how to filter list which is inside List of class using linq?

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

```
class A
{
    List<Package> productPackages;
}


static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<A> mainProductListing;
    }
```

How can I filter `mainProductListing.productPacakge` where `productPackage.fileName="somefile.msi"` usin Linq?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var list = mainProductListing.Where(t=>t.productPackages.Any(s=>s.fileName == "somefile.msi"));
```

Comment: var list= mainProductListing.Select(item=>item.fileName.Eruals("somefile.msi"));

Comment: was that this much easy? I really need to brush-up my skill.. Thanks for the reply